# Attempt to create a command with 2 arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make a command so that I enter two names and these names are identified as Query1 and Query2, however, I don't know how to do it, can someone help me?

```
const {MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js');

module.exports ={
    name : 'battle',
    aliases: ['batalha'],
    run : async(client, message) => {
        
        await message.delete();

        const query1 = args[0].join(" ");
        if(!query1) return message.reply('Adicione o primeiro nome!');

        const query2 = args[1].join(" ");
        if(!query2) return message.reply('Adicione o segundo nome!')

        var embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setAuthor('BATALHA DE FOTOS', client.user.avatarURL)
        .setDescription(`Marque o emoji de acordo com o seu voto: \n\n ${query1}:  \n${query2}: `)
        .setFooter(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/1oHJJZQ.png')

        const msg = await message.channel.send(embed)
        await msg.react('')
        await msg.react('')
        
    }
}
```

> Error

```
(node:864) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: args is not defined
    at Object.run (C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\RemakeGANGBOT\commands\info\battle.js:10:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:864) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:864) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: What error are you getting (if any)?

Comment: (node:10872) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: args is not defined
    at Object.run

Comment: Well, you haven't defined `args`, where is args expected to come from?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you aren't defining `args`. You can define it before running any code for your command by using:

```js
const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);
```